Using the Microsoft Graph API to load files from Sharepoint into Databricks
I want to load files from Sharepoint using a Microsoft App registration and the Microsoft Graph API. Right now I get the error that I am not authotized but I do not know if I just do not have the necessary permissions or if I did something wrong about the path of the file I want to load. I have the Sites.Read.All and Sites.Select permissions. Can anyone help me? My code looks like this:
sharepoint_site = "company_name.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name"
sharepoint_file_path = "relative_path/file.xlsx"
client_id = dbutils.secrets.get("secret_scope", "client_id")
tenant_id = dbutils.secrets.get("secret_scope", "tenant_id")
client_secret = dbutils.secrets.get("secret_scope", "client_secret")

auth_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
auth_data = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}

auth_response = requests.post(auth_url, data=auth_data)
if auth_response.status_code != 200:
    print("Fehler bei der Authentifizierung")
    print(auth_response.text)
    exit()

access_token = auth_response.json().get("access_token")

headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
download_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{sharepoint_site}/drive/root:/{sharepoint_file_path}:/content"
file_response = requests.get(download_url, headers=headers)
if file_response.status_code == 200:
    file_path = "/dbfs/path.xlsx"
    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(file_response.content)
    print("Datei heruntergeladen!")
else:
    print(f"Fehler: {file_response.status_code}")
    print(file_response.text)


what is your expected output here?

@RakeshGovindula sorry, I edited the code, I want to save the file in the dbfs

Have you checked the value of auth_response.status_code in your attempt? can you provide it?

@RakeshGovindula 403 so it seems like I am not authorized but since I have the Sites.read.all permission this should not be the case Ort am I wrong?

Grant Files.Read.All api permission to the application with Application permission type.

After getting access token make sure you are having roles,
you check this in jwt.io by pasting the token.

Next, you get the site id using below code.
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}

site_res = requests.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/sites/<site_name>",headers=headers)
site_id = site_res.json()['id']

Then you make request to get the file with below code.
download_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drive/root:/Identity AR.xlsx:/content"

file_response = requests.get(download_url, headers=headers)
print(file_response.status_code)
if file_response.status_code == 200:
    file_path = "/dbfs/identity.xlsx"
    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(file_response.content)
    print(f"file created")
else:
    print(file_response.status_code)



Thank you for your answer! Could you explain why I need the Files.Read.All permission instead of the Sites.Read.All permission? I thought that Sites.Read.All would basically allow me to read all files on the site

AFAIK Files.Read.All API permission is required to perform the action I'm also checking for more information

Files.Read.All is the least privileged permissions, that's working and Sites.Read.All is Higher privileged permissions there is something to do with that I guess
